# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error ANDROID

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem with this block of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = json_data.getString("post_title");
    String created_date = json_data.getString("created_date");
    String outPut = name + "-" + created_date;
    postList.add(createPost("blog_posts", outPut));
    Log.e("log_tag", "Name: "+name);
}
```

And I am getting this error.

```
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-26 22:55:18.642: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
```

This question may have duplicates but I have tried searching answers but none of them helped. Any help would be appreciated.

**This works fine when I remove this block of code**.

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    MainActivity.this, postList, R.layout.postlist,
    new String[] {"posts"},
    new int[] {R.id.post_title,R.id.posted_date});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


private HashMap<String, String> createPost(
    String name, String created_date) {
    HashMap<String, String> blogitem = new HashMap<String, String>();
    blogitem.put(name, created_date);
    return blogitem;
}
```

Comment: how much objects does your json array contains?it seems it has only one

Comment: Are you sure the logcat brings you to the lines of code you've attached?

Comment: agree with Sean..this code seems to be ok..

Comment: index out of bound is not compile time error,so the code will seem OK ,but the issue might be due to lesser no of objects in jarray,i guess her problem is due to bad assignment of values to jarray

Comment: I just deleted my answer because it actually doesn't look like there is an error with this portion.  Are you sure that the out of bounds exception refers to this location?

Comment: Check the field `postList` and function `createPost()` . I'm quite sure that the exception is caused from that space if the logcat points to your codeblock.